# Avoid js script loading when API call using content security policy (CSP)

Tags: javascript, java, html, browser, content-security-policy

Our security team scanned and reported "An attack could leverage on the XSS vulnerability to inject malicious scripts and further exploit the web application."

"The test team recommends the use of the Content Security Policy (CSP)."

So we added the following content security policy in server.
Content-Security-Policy:
"default-src 'self' https://*.mywebsite2.com https://*.mywebsite1.net https://*.mywebsite3.com; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://*.mywebsite2.com https://*.mywebsite1.net https://*.mywebsite3.com https://*.googleapis.com https://*.google-analytics.com; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';img-src 'self' https://*.mywebsite2.com https://*.mywebsite1.net https://*.mywebsite3.com https://*.gstatic.com; font-src 'self';frame-src 'self' https://*.mywebsite2.com https://*.mywebsite1.net https://*.mywebsite3.com; frame-ancestors 'self';connect-src 'self' https://*.mywebsite2.com https://*.mywebsite1.net https://*.mywebsite3.com https://*.googleapis.com; base-uri 'self';"

But when calling from API from one of the field ,"onerror=console.log(2)" is executing and showing up in browser console.
[image]

[image]

What change should i do in CSP to avoid this?

Any help will be appreciated, Thanks in advance..